# That last scene in The Final Cut

Tags: plot-explanation, the-final-cut

In the final scene in The Final Cut 2004, we are shown a memory of Alan's being played. He is in front of a mirror, hence we see his face. Alan walks out of the frame and the memory continues to show the mirror. How is this possible? What was the relevance of this scene?